# How to copy rough 'illustrated' lines?

Tags: illustration, line-art

I am trying to copy the line style in the following images:

[image]
[image]

This is what I've arrived at:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can improve it to get it to look like the above ones? :/

Comment: As I commented previously, before you deleted that same question.... pencil, paper.. *draw* and scan. Creating an effective and believable hand drawn appearance digitally can take considerable experience and practice. And if you don't possess a drawing tablet, even more so. There is *no* filter, effect, or plug in that's going to do this for you. Artists have jobs for a *reason*.

Comment: No problem, your lines already resemble the ones shown in the question - I mean they have twists and width variations. The 1st example in the question has more of them with different colors and there's also wide black areas on the red. Your lines are maybe not the best  to present the curvature of the petals. But that's a wider drawing problem than how to draw lines. It's how to make them look a shading The problem is discussed in numerous cases. One example https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155665/how-do-i-create-spiked-shading-in-illustrator Finally it's the ability to draw.

Comment: (continued) Most of the existing old cases talk about imitating the work of carvers and engravers. Artificial intelligence programmers may succeed to copy the line shading style from a vast collection of same style different images and to condense it to an automatic program. The rest of us must practice to make it manually. It can take years to become fast and confident in it for all kinds of shapes. And that happens only if one has got between his ears what the job takes. But your lines have so much already that I believe you have at least got the idea, so GO ON!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example image has a kind of hand made woodcut/linocut print look, as if the shading was carved out with chisels.

To achieve a similar effect, I would draw it manually with the Pen tool (Bézier tool) in vector software, such as Illustrator or Inkscape, etc. If you are trying to use the pencil tool with a brush it might just be a bit too regular. The point here is not to have perfect Bézier curves or uniform lines, but varying slightly irregular paths.

1. Draw a petal shape, and apply a red fill and black stroke.
2. For the inside shading lines, draw the strokes not as single strokes, but as closed shapes with a black fill, using the Pen Tool. Slightly more irregular shapes are possible as you can easily tweak the Bézier paths to make them look more irregular if needed.
3. Try to concentrate the shading lines towards the bottom of the petal so that is becomes almost solid black towards the bottom of the petal. That will make it look more like shading.

An example of just one petal, hovering over the shapes to show their paths. The example was made in Inkscape, but the same is possible in all vector software.

[image]

5. Once you have one petal, group it, duplicate, and rotate around a central origin.
6. Flip a few of the petals, modify the petal outlines to give a bit more irregularity, delete a few of the details on some of the petals.
7. Add a black filled circle in the middle, and some filled ellipses to make little red stipples in the middle.
8. Place over a black background.

[image]

9. Group and duplicate copies of the flowers, rotate some, scale some larger/smaller, apply a slight perspective distort on some copies.

[image]

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but also roughened the lines using a distortion. Check it out below! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Followed Billy's advice and also applied a roughen effect to the paths. Looks exactly the same!

[image]

Comment: Cool! Nice to see that the answer actually helped improve your result. But you should add this to your *question* by editing it and delete this *answer* to keep the site tidy. 